# Sentence comparison: how to highlight differences

Tags: python, pandas, cosine-similarity, fuzzywuzzy, sentence-similarity

I have the following sequences of strings within a column in pandas:

```
SEQ
An empty world
So the word is
So word is
No word is
```

I can check the similarity using fuzzywuzzy or cosine distance.
However I would like to know how to get information about the word which changes position from amore to another.
For example:
Similarity between the first row and the second one is 0. But here is similarity between row 2 and 3.
They present almost the same words and the same position. I would like to visualize this change (missing word) if possible. Similarly to the 3rd row and the 4th.
How can I see the changes between two rows/texts?

Comment: Are you interested in comparing consecutive rows as per your example or all possible combinations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using jupyter / ipython and you are just interested in comparisons between a row and that preceding it I would do something like this.

The general concept is:

- find shared tokens between the two strings (by splitting on ' ' and finding the intersection of two sets).
- apply some html formatting to the tokens shared between the two strings.
- apply this to all rows.
- output the resulting dataframe as html and render it in ipython.

```
import pandas as pd 

data = ['An empty world',
        'So the word is',
        'So word is',
        'No word is']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['phrase'])

bold = lambda x: f'<b>{x}</b>'

def highlight_shared(string1, string2, format_func):
    shared_toks = set(string1.split(' ')) & set(string2.split(' '))
    return ' '.join([format_func(tok) if tok in shared_toks else tok for tok in string1.split(' ') ])

highlight_shared('the cat sat on the mat', 'the cat is fat', bold)

df['previous_phrase'] = df.phrase.shift(1, fill_value='')
df['tokens_shared_with_previous'] = df.apply(lambda x: highlight_shared(x.phrase, x.previous_phrase, bold), axis=1)

from IPython.core.display import HTML

HTML(df.loc[:, ['phrase', 'tokens_shared_with_previous']].to_html(escape=False))
```

Comment: Hi âme, thank you for your answer. I have got this error: NameError: name 'apply_formats' is not defined . Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Yes - I've edited the code and it now runs :) I replaced a function called 'apply_formats' in to 'highlight_shared'.